# Is it possible to have a table linking to a table that is linking back to the first table using foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Im playing around with MySQL at the moment, learning stuff about database design and wondered something i couldnt find an answer to in Google.

Imagine a table named 'products' with the primary key 'id' and two additional columns named 'name' and 'primary_image_id', where 'primary_image_id' is a foreign key linking to a second table.

The second table is named 'product_images' also with the primary key 'id' and two additional columns this time called 'path' (path to the image) and 'product_id'. 'product_id' is of course a foreign key linking back to the first table.

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| id |   name    | primary_image_id |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | product_A |         3        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 2  | product_B |         6        |
+----+-----------+------------------+

+----+-----------+------------------+
| id |   path    |    product_id    |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | /image_01 |         2        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 2  | /image_02 |         1        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 3  | /image_03 |         1        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 4  | /image_04 |         1        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 5  | /image_05 |         2        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 6  | /image_06 |         2        |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

The idea is to have a table with all product images while only one image per product is the preview image (primary image). Is this type of foreign key linking even possible? And if yes, is it good databse design or should I use an other method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you can answer this partially yourself: Did it work, when you tried it out?

Comment: "Good Database Design" is somewhat opinionated. You'd have to define, what "good" means. However, what you could do alternatively, is two more tables: "PrimaryProductImages" which associates Products to Primary Images 1:1 by ids, and "ProductImages" which just associates all the Images to the Products by id 1:n (Product:Images).

Comment: Or ... you introduce a fourth column in the images table: bool "isPrimary" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid use case and the table design looks good if your intention is to just read data using foreign key like "Get all image paths for product id 1" or "Get primary image of product id 1" or "Get paths of all primary images".

People tend to avoid the cycle of foreign key reference in tables specially if there is a cascade dependency on delete/update events. You need to answer questions like "What should happen to image 2, 3 ,4 if product 1 is deleted" or "what should happen to product 1 if image 3 is deleted".

The answers would help you come with a design that fulfills your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Just use indexes without `FOREIGN KEYs`.

Answer (score 0):

A more typical approach would be to move the primary flag to the images table. Both of these approaches have the potential for illogical data —

Your way would allow product 1 to name image A as its primary while image A could identify product 2 as its product.

My way would allow products to have 0 or 2+ primary images if the flag wasn’t well-managed.

Depending on how worried you are about either inconsistency, you could try to manage it via triggers or constraints, although MySQL is a little lacking in these areas compared to other DBMSs.

One way to absolutely prevent a problem would be to have the primary flag in the images table, but use it as an int (rank), not a Boolean with a convention that minimum rank is the “primary” — create a unique index on the combination of (product ID,  rank) — and access this data via a stored proc or view that could implement the rank convention for you, e.g. `select * from images a where product_id = whatever and does not exist (select 1 from images b where a.product_id = b.product_id and a.rank > b.rank)`.

Seems like overkill, but you need to be the judge how important potential data integrity issues are for your application.